# getting wrong date format (coping from one excel spreadsheet to another)

Tags: vba, date, csv, format

I'm pretty new to VBA though have done quite a bit of coding many years ago.

I am creating a macro that copies a column of data from a csv file to another excel spreadsheet (which I've labelled wkb1). The data in the csv file is for date and time and appears like this  "09/12/2015 14:19" (for example).
Since it's just a csv file which is opened in Excel (within my macro) it does not have any pre-assigned formats.

The above example is supposed to represent the 9th of December (NOT 12th of September). My Windows location is set for the date format to be DDMMYYYY (ie English not US format).

When I manually copy and paste (or paste-special) from the csv to my working spreadsheet, it copies the data, as is (ie as text), into the working spreadsheet. It does not convert the data to an actual date & time value.

But if I use the exact same steps in a macro (which I will show you below)
then the data comes through converted to date:time AND it swaps around the month and date - so it is pasted either as 2015/09/12  02:19:00 PM or as 42259.60 (depending on whether I have used paste or paste-special in the macro)

Because of this alarming swapping of the month and date, I want avoid this risk and bring the data in just as text and then deconstruct the text to recreate the correct date (using the DateSerial function)

My code for copying the text across looks, quite simply, like this:
(starting in the csv file active, which I open earlier within the macro)

```
Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, 1).Offset(x, 4)).Copy
wkb1.Activate
Cells(4, "W").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Any suggestions for a robust solution? Any risk of the date and month order being swapped from English to US format will be a disaster for me!
thanks
Damian

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the range that will be pasted into as text format before you perform the special paste.

```
Cells(4, "W").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@" 'Numbers will be stored as text
Selection.PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, _
    Transpose:=False
```